# applescript moves Terminal and Finder windows fine, but not Chrome window

Tags: applescript

This moves the windows of Finder and Terminal, but for some reason does not work with other apps, say Google Chrome, as in the code below

```
tell application "System Events"
    
    set activeApp to name of application processes whose frontmost is true
    do shell script "echo activeApp " & quoted form of (activeApp as string) & ¬
        " >> ~/Desktop/as_debug.txt"
    
    
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        do shell script "echo count windows " & quoted form of ((count windows) as string) & ¬
            " >> ~/Desktop/as_debug.txt"
        repeat with x from 1 to (count windows)
            set position of window x to {0, 22}
        end repeat
        
    end tell
    
end tell
```

The error is rather obscure:
`Can’t make position of window 1 into type reference.`

Any clue on what Applescript is complaining about and why that works for Finder and Terminal

Comment: You will need to check the Google Chrome scripting dictionary. Terminology is up to the developer - there is no guarantee that any given term does the same thing in different applications.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that `tell application` is not doing it, but `tell process` is.

```
set theApp to "Spotify"


tell application "Finder"
    set screenResolution to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

set screenWidth to item 3 of screenResolution
set screenHeight to item 4 of screenResolution



tell application "System Events"
    tell process theApp
        repeat with x from 1 to (count windows)
            set the size of window x to {screenWidth / 2, screenHeight}
            set position of window x to {0 + 0 * screenWidth / 2, 22}
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```